# CSV with German Characters Encoding Issue

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, character

A colleague of mine from Germany sent me a csv with german addresses that were not converted properly, when I open it in excel or in notepad the following names appear, see bellow:

KÃ¶nigsberger Weg, KirchenstraÃŸe ,Am GehÃ¶lz

Should be:

Königsberger Weg, Kirchenstraße,Am Gehölz

Would it be possible to convert it or that could only be done in the original file?

I have tried converting it using notepad, notepad++, or in excel using the data tab options.

Used various encoding options too, utf8, utf8 bom, but nothing worked.

I dont have access to the source of the original file, I can only work with the csv file I have, I would like to correct it if possible.

My german colleagues also encounter the same issue so I think the encoding mistake happened when the original file was created.

Hope this clarifies.

Edit 1 - Following Deceze suggestion I did the following:

Used the hex editor, in the cvs the headers appear correctly, for example the word bellow has this bytes sequence Straße 53 74 72 61 c3 9f 65 While the wrong one has this bytes sequence StraÃŸe 53 74 72 61 c3 83 c5 I dont know how to fix it now tho.

If it could be fixed using python, it would be great.

Edit 2 -  Here is a link to the source file.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r5-mDSr_PJN2PSMAl7w_XWcS3gvQgeSx5-Z1mDkqF9g/edit#gid=1259155446

Comment: What are the actual bytes? Use a hex editor to check that? Are they *actually* broken characters, or are you merely misinterpreting them in the wrong encoding? Does this need to be fixed after the fact, or is there something to fix where you produce that CSV? Or mightn't there be any issue at all, and you're just opening the file incorrectly?

Comment: I have notepad++ and I installed an hex editor to view the file, but I dont know what I should be checking, can you explain?

Comment: You want to see what *bytes* the file actually contains, e.g. something like `4bc3 83c2 b66e` for `KÃ¶n`. A hex editor can show you that. Based on that you can investigate what encoding that might be, and whether it's correct or not. Based on *that* you can decide if you need to fix how that CSV is produced (if the encoding/bytes are incorrect), or if you need to fix this after the fact somehow, or if you're just incorrectly interpreting that encoding when opening the file.

Comment: I used the hex editor, in the cvs the headers appear correctly, for example the word bellow has this bytes sequence

Straße 53 74 72 61 c3 9f 65

While the wrong one has this bytes sequence

StraÃŸe   53 74 72 61 c3 83 c5

I dont know how to fix it now tho

Comment: Put this information into your question! Also indicate what languages you may want to use to fix this.

Comment: Preliminarily one can say that it appears that you have 1) a mixed encoding, with the headers being proper UTF-8, and the data being mojibake, and 2) that the data appears to have been proper UTF-8 at some point, which got interpreted as Latin-1 or something like that, and then those interpreted characters got encoded to UTF-8. So you'd need to reverse that chain of misinterpretation and encoding, but only for the data rows, not the headers.

Comment: These issues usually happen when text is cut&pasted from app to app.  Instead, email it as an attachment. Also, view it on linux (will show hex by default instead of changing it into what it thinks it should be when it dos not know what it is), don't use Microsoft stuff.  0x93 is particularly problematic (grey range not "standardized"--see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1, etc..  It is Microsoft's infamous "smart quote" which is actually <ctrl,Q> = XOFF but with the MSb (but ASCII is only 7 bits) set to 1.

Comment: Sometimes, without knowing a priori the encoding,, it literally a guessing game (there are many [old] standard AND proprietary formats).  Thank God, the world is settling on UTF-8--but it will take years for old stuff to die off.

Comment: It's a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case as `'straße,Am Gehölz'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'straÃŸe,Am GehÃ¶lz'`

Answer (score 4):

Your data seems to be encoded as UTF-8, but only after it was mis-decoded as Windows-1252 (or maybe `latin1`) when it was originally UTF-8.  You didn't provide enough bytes in your edit to decode it fully, but enough were there that I could determine what the rest were:

```
>>> b = '53 74 72 61 c3 83 c5 b8 65'
>>> bytes.fromhex(b).decode('utf8')
'StraÃŸe'
>>> bytes.fromhex(b).decode('utf8').encode('cp1252').decode('utf8')
'Straße'
```

The link provided wasn't the raw text of `content.csv`, but assuming it is mis-decoding, this would work:

```py
with open('content.csv',encoding='utf8') as f:
    data = f.read().encode('cp1252').decode('utf8')
print(data)
# Excel needs UTF-8 w/ BOM encoding to read a UTF-8 file correctly.
with open('corrected.csv','w',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Output:

```
Bullmersberg
Reiterweg
Spadener Weg
Land Wurster Straße
Raiffeisenweg
Steinackerweg
Im Wiesengrund
Wehdener Straße
Langener Straße
Hinter der Mühle
Zwischen den Seen
Bahnhofsallee
Am Gehölz
Am Dulmer Acker
Im Ruschviertel
Widackerring
Am Pfarrhaus
Am Seepark
Kolberger Straße
```

Comment: Thank you, I have uploaded the source file.

I will try to work with the code you shared.